# crtmpserver error, appselector can be a final destination

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, rtmpd

I'm trying to setup a CRTMP serve by using its script run and its default script  crtmpserver.lua. my os is centos6, and kenerl version 2.6.32.

The server start ok, showes
/crtmpserver/src/crtmpserver.cpp:267 GO! GO! GO!

But when i use ffmpeg to push a flv stream, using the command 
ffmpeg -re -i test.flv -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/appselector/room1

it shows the error
RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet header
rtmp://localhost:1935/appselector/room1: Operation not permitted

and the crtmpserver shows the following error

/applications/appselector/src/rtmpappprotocolhandler.cpp:66 appselector can be a final destination

/thelib/src/protocols/rtmp/basertmpprotocol.cpp:1049 Unable to send rtmp message
to application

/thelib/src/netio/epoll/tcpcarrier.cpp:89 Unable to signal data available

/thelib/src/netio/epoll/iohandlermanager.cpp:130 Handlers count changed: 11->10 IOHT_TCP_CARRIER

/thelib/src/protocols/protocolmanager.cpp:45 Enqueue for delete for protocol [IR(3)]

/thelib/src/application/baseclientapplication.cpp:246 Protocol [IR(3)] unregistered from application: appselector

Does the default lua config has some wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I try many times for modifying lua config and success finally.

I remove the comment of aliases to make aliases work

--aliases(this comment do not remove)
{
    "simpleLive",
    "vod",
    "live",
},

Run the command 
 ffmpeg -re -i test.flv -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live/room1

and it work!

I dont't know the reason